# Send XML SOAP request in Laravel 4

Tags: php, soap, laravel

Does Laravel 4 have a library to send XML SOAP Requests, or is there a proper way to do this in Laravel instead of doing it manually with CURL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel does not contain any XML/SOAP libraries out of the box.

However, since Laravel is composer-friendly, you can use any [SOAP Composer package](https://packagist.org/search/?q=soap).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but PHP itself has a very nice class called [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) which you can use to send SOAP requests in a couple of lines. There's definitely no need to do it with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in PHP [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) Class in Laravel

by simply adding SoapClient class in **app/config.php** aliases Array

```
'SoapClient' => SoapClient::class
```

And whenever you want to use SoapClient Class just add
`use SoapClient;` in the file.